# How to know which button was clicked so that I can open webpages in the same activity?

Tags: javascript, android, android-listview

May be the question is not clear. Let me put it like this.

I am making a android app in eclipse. I am making a web app. I have around ten links to open in the app. But I donot want to make 10 different activity. Instead I want to make a switch case when 1st position was clicked on the list view open this link or if 3rd position is clicked then open another link. I am using webView so I have to enable javascript and so many other things. So if I make 10 activities and copy the same code on each and every activity, the size of the app is huge.

So want to make a reusable activity so that I can just use switch case or if case.

if 1st position was clicked than open this link.
if 2nd position was clicked than open that link.
and so on. 
anybody with java for android knowledge. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to send a URL to an activity while starting it? If that's the case, you can pass the parameter by using Intent's

```
intent.putExtra(String key, String value);
// e.g. intent.putExtra("url", "http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

...on the intent you're using to start the activity and

```
getIntent().getStringExtra(String key)
// e.g. getIntent().getStringExtra("url")
```

...to pull the parameter in the activity itself, e.g. in its onCreate() method.

Comment: thanks man but I am really new to android programming. Need more detail. Can you give me some example of source code. In a easy way to ask I want to know how to how to know which list item were clicked on the previous activity.

Comment: Your list code would really help. In general though, you can't just know that directly in the next activity, you have to catch the event in your list activity. There are various ways, you could either attach OnClickListener to the list items themselves or use the list.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) method which is even easier. Once you receive the OnClick/OnItemClick event, you construct an intent with the parameter you need and use it to start the second activity.

Comment: I have three activity. Out of those three activity two activity are the listview and the third one is the webview.

Comment: I have three activity. Out of those three activity two activity are the listvew and the third one is the webview. when you click on the one of the list on the 1st activity and it opens second listview activity and when you click one of the listview in 2nd activity it opens webview activity.  think it like this. you have threenews channel. on the 1st activity three news channel are listed.on the 2nd activity the sub list of the respective news channel are listed and when you click on the sublist, the new webpage that is loaded should be the sublink form that 1st news channel that you selected.

Comment: Yep, it seems like using list.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) for your ListViews and using intent.putExtra(String key, String value)/getExtra(String key) is just what you need. Read up on starting activities with intents if you're not sure how the code goes.

Comment: I have created different question with source code. may be you could help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577002/how-to-open-different-webpage-from-same-activity-from-the-listview-which-has-dif).

Comment: It's not too good to duplicate questions, but I answered over there anyway.